# Jquery .post not sending data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the Wordpress heartbeat and am attempting to pass some data to my site using Ajax. I am able to see the action in my $_POST but my data is not available. The below .post is able to send a request to MyZabbix, that post contains my action, my action then works. However, I need access to the indexs['hosted']. Why would the below .post not send my data when sending the action?

```
     $( document ).on( 'heartbeat-tick', function( e, data ) {
         $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
             $.each( value, function( indexs, values ) {
                 var hostids = indexs['hostid'];
                 $.post( MyZabbix.ajaxurl, {
                     action:'zabbix_ajax_submit',
                     data: indexs['hostid']  },
                     function( api_response ) {
                         console.log( "Data Saved: " + api_response );
                 });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: @Terry It'd probably be more helpful if you were to give an overview of how the usage is incorrect and then link the docs to back it up.

Comment: Considering the fact that it works... It would be tremendously helpful to know how it is wrong?...

Comment: It's fine, `$.post(url, {data}, callback)` is totally valid.

Comment: However doing ajax inside two nested loops probably isn't a very good idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the when function with my ajax request. The issue that I was experiencing was - My ajax request didn't always finish before the rest of my code executed. By moving my code into a function that executed only AFTER my ajax request was successful, I was then able to get every thing to behave as expected.

```
 var promise = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: MyZabbix.ajaxurl,
      async: true,
      data: { action:'zabbix_ajax_submit', data:value}
 });
 $.when(promise).done( successFunction );
```

The when function is located in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

The done function is located in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).